# How can I use a drupal variable to dynamically change a Views field?

Tags: views

I'm trying to change a View field output depending upon a user's IP.

There's a double conditional I need to accommodate:  If the user is outside of an IP range, and if the selected content is restricted, display Restricted Text.

My IP detect works fine, and the Restricted Text works manually, but I can't connect the two.

I have tried using tokens, drupal variables, and Header Global Text fields, but I can't access them within the View.

I looked at Filters, Behaviours without success, and D7 won't let me use php to rewrite the field results.

Creating a custom view lets me add ['content'] to a header, but not a field, and passing in a variable to the ['field'] returns an error (expecting an object maybe?).

The last day has been spent trying to make a handler for that field (modifying a recipe from Views Cookbook) but it isn't commented well enough for me to figure out what I'm trying to do with it.

I feel like I've run out of climbing pegs and can't make it up the Drupal Cliff.  I'm ready to hard code it and call it a day.

What am I missing??

Comment: You can do almost anything with a Views template.  cd to ..../views/theme and take a look at views-view-field.tpl.php.  It can me copied to your theme (or module with additional effort) and modified per field.  Look at the theme information via the Views UI for more information/assistance as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I had narrowed it down to theme templates and handlers, so I will have another look knowing that I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you can simply use [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module and access and modify the data before it's rendered in the view. What this does is add a custom field in the view through which you can do operations on the fields rendered. However this is not optimal as the code is stored in the database and this will be hard to maintain and extend.

If it's a simple operation, you can go ahead and use it (like in your case, a simple condition), but if you want it to be easily maintained and extended use custom templates for the view itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook into the view before it's rendered. There are a list of hooks that could be used to do this - https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7

You'll need to create a custom module to place your hook into first.

If you output the contents of [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) and [hook_views_post_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_post_render/7) you should be able to see where to add in your additional logic.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I had built my own view module as well as a handler module but not seeing any results.  Thanks for the hooks, now I will try again and see where I'm at.